# HQL UNION of fields from two tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

Am very much new to hive, have very basic idea about it, so please pardon me if its silly:

The below data is just an example of what am trying to do, the actual data is really huge.

I have 2 tables:

Table A

**id1  name source**

101  aa  SAP

102  bb   SAP

103  cc   SAP

Table B

**id2  name source**

106 zz   SAP

107 yy   SAP

108 xx   SAP

I need to create another table C with schema

**id Name Strorage**

with all ids and names from table A and B, and another column "Storage" which has to be hard coded with 'HDFS'

I need output like:

**id  name  Strorage**

101  aa   HDFS

102  bb   HDFS

103  cc   HDFS

106  zz   HDFS

107  yy   HDFS

108  xx   HDFS

I have tried many queries but 1 among them is as follows:

```
insert into table c select (select * from (select id1 from A union select id2 from B)) as id, (select * from (select name from A union select name from B)) as name , 'HDFS' as Strorage;
```

but it gives error "ParseException line 1:53 cannot recognize input near 'select' '*' 'from' in expression specification"

Am not sure if the query am trying is the right one, please help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the (first) syntax problem is in your insert, not the union query.  Something like this should work:

```
insert into table c select id, name, 'HDFS' from (
  select * from (select id1, name from A union select id2, name from B));
```

Comment: Thank u so much sir for replying:

Comment: but i get error saying: ParseException line 3:80 cannot recognize input near ')' '<EOF>' in subquery source

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working query:

```
insert into table c select distinct * from (select id1, name, 'HDFS' storage from a union all select id1, name, 'HDFS' storage from b) c;
```

Some versions does not support union, there is only union all to simulate union you have to use distinct.

When field names are different, you have to try this:

```
insert into table c select distinct * from (select id1, name, 'HDFS' storage from a union all select id2 as id1, name, 'HDFS' storage from b) c;
```

Comment: Thank for replying sir. I tried this but am getting error saying: 'SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 5:22 Invalid table alias or column reference 'id1': (possible column names are: id2, name)'  and when I changed it to 'id2' in sub- query I got error 'SemanticException TOK_ALLCOLREF is not supported in current context'

Comment: What is the final query you are using after necessary modifications?

Comment: Also paste the DDL of all the 3 tables

Comment: Column names in both the sub queries needs to be same. As you have id1 in a and id2 in b, you have to provide alias.